# Entity framework transfer thousands of objects to Elastic Search

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nest

I am creating a web app that will have a database on every town, region and country in the world to allow for mapping other objects to a location. As part of the application I want the users to be able to search for a place, to do this I am using Elastic Search to index everything. To interact with Elastic Search I am using NEST.

I have the following code:

```
public void RefreshLocationIndex()
{
    int count;
    using (var dbContext = new ModelContext())
    {
        IndexMany(dbContext.Countries, "Country");
    }

    using (var dbContext = new ModelContext())
    {
        count = dbContext.Regions.AsNoTracking().Count();
    }
    for (var i = 0; i <= count; i += BATCH_SIZE)
    {
        using (var innerContext = new ModelContext())
        {
            IndexMany(innerContext.Regions.OrderBy(t => t.RegionID).Skip(i).Take(BATCH_SIZE),
                    "Region");
        }
    }


    using (var dbContext = new ModelContext())
    {
        count = dbContext.Towns.AsNoTracking().Count();
    }
    for (var i = 0; i <= count; i += BATCH_SIZE)
    {
        using (var innerContext = new ModelContext())
        {
            IndexMany(innerContext.Towns.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(t => t.TownID).Skip(i).Take(BATCH_SIZE), "Town");
        }
    }
}

public void IndexMany(IQueryable<Entity> objects, string type)
{
    var itemCount = objects.Count();
    if (itemCount > 0)
    {
        SearchClient.Instance.IndexManyAsync(objects, SearchClient.Instance.Settings.DefaultIndex, type);
    }
}
```

As you can see I am separating the very large tables into batches to try to avoid loading to much into memory. The problem is this is not working, and I keep getting out of memory exceptions. I thought that using a new context for each batch would avoid this issue as when the context was disposed it would dispose of all the entities it had loaded, this doesn't seem to be the case. Any ideas?

Just as an indication of the amount of data:
  Country table has 193 records
  Region table has 80,523 records
  Town table has 2,743,469 records

Comment: is it wise to create and dispose your big dbcontext 80,523 times for only region and 2,743,469 for towns?

Comment: you need to wait for IndexManyAsync to finish adderwise you put everything in memory while you wait for it to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about ElasticSearch nor NEST, but according to [their source code](https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/blob/master/src/Nest/ElasticClient-Index.cs) , `IndexManyAsync` creates a new task each time it is called.

So if tasks are executed much slower than Entity Framework materializes your entities, you'll have a huge number of tasks that are executing (or waiting to execute), each task having `BATCH_SIZE` entities loaded in memory as those entities are passed as parameter: so basically all your entities will be loaded in memory at the same time.

I'm not sure how to solve this because I don't known the best practices with NEST or ElasticSearch regarding to batch indexes, but here's the explanation for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Object is only eligible for garbage collection if there are no live references to it.
Clearly you have disposed the context but you probably still have references to the entities that are not so apparent.  Somewhere inside SearchClient.Instance.IndexManyAsync(objects, ...) you must still be holding a reference to objects.

In this example, memory will not be reclaimed when dbContext is disposed.

```
List<Region> regions;
using (var dbContext = new ModelContext())
{
    regions = dbContext.Regions.ToList();  
}  //dbContext is disposed, but memory is not reclaimed.
regions = null; //memory is reclaimed
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you be missing `AsNoTracking()` for `dbContext.Countries` and `innerContext.Regions`? When you use the ChangeTracker, it will going to keep references in memory until the queried entities references are gone.

In your case, it's probably increasing your memory because the multiple contexts (mainly the innerContext for Regions) are actually not being disposed due to the ChangeTracker.

Just try to use AsNoTracking for all the queries and check the memory footprint again.

Still in your case, by not using AsNoTracking, all the tracked entities are being passed to your SearchClient method, then you can't know when these references will actually be released.

If the problem is not related to EF itself, try to find the memory leak using a tool like [ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/), it's very useful.